# Wierd action bar tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I created an action bar style with ANDROID ACTION BAR STYLE GENERATOR i copied the generated theme and integrated it into my app but when i run the app the action bar is blurred http://postimg.org/image/ox2saxhkt/ is a screen shot of how it looks

I've searched the web and stackoverflow but i haven't seen anyone with this kind of issue before i've done a rebuild i've tested it tdifferent emulators and it is still the same i even removed the 4.4W and 4.4L and used the 4.4.2 library to build it but no success

NOTE:I'm running on linux Kubuntu.

This is the code below

```
package com.pico;

import com.pico.sales.R;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;


public class Set extends FragmentActivity implements
ActionBar.TabListener {
CollectionPagerAdapter mCollectionPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       mCollectionPagerAdapter = new CollectionPagerAdapter(
       getSupportFragmentManager());

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCollectionPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager
    .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override

        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

    });
for (int i = 0; i < mCollectionPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
.setText(mCollectionPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
.setTabListener(this));
}

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public class CollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


final int NUM_ITEMS = 4; // number of tabs

public CollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
super(fm);

}

/** This method will be invoked when a page is requested to create */
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch(position) {
    case 0:
        return new Tab1();
    case 1:
        return new Tab2();
    case 2:
        return new Tab3();
    case 3:
        return new Tab4();
    default:
        return null;
}
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

return NUM_ITEMS;

}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
String tabLabel = null;
switch (position) {
    case 0:
        tabLabel = "Dashboard";
        break;
    case 1:
        tabLabel = "Invoices";
        break;
    case 2:
        tabLabel = "Inventory";
        break;
    case 3:
        tabLabel = "Reports";
        break;
}

return tabLabel;

}
}



}
```

and this is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pico.sales"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
         android:maxSdkVersion="19"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Pico" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.pico.MainActivity"
            android:label="Please Login" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.START" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.pico.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.pico.Set"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.pico.Register"
            android:label="Setup Your Account"
            android:icon="@drawable/new_user" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.REGISTER" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.pico.Setup"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SETUP" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.pico.Items"
            android:parentActivityName="com.pico.Set" >
            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support API level 7+ -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.pico.Set"
            android:label="Items" >
                </meta-data>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ITEMS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.pico.No_items"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NO_ITEMS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.pico.Pricing"
            android:parentActivityName="com.pico.Set" >
            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support API level 7+ -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.pico.Set"
            android:label="Pricing Schemes" >
                </meta-data>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PRICING" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.pico.No_pricing"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NO_PRICING" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:icon="@drawable/new_user"
            android:name="com.pico.Customers"
            android:parentActivityName="com.pico.Set" >
            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support API level 7+ -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.pico.Set"
            android:label="Customers" >
                </meta-data>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CUSTOMERS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:icon="@drawable/new_user"
            android:name="com.pico.No_customers" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NO_CUSTOMERS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:icon="@drawable/new_user"
            android:name="com.pico.Add_customer"
            android:parentActivityName="com.pico.Customers" >
            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support API level 7+ -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.pico.Customers"
            android:label="Add_customer" >
                </meta-data>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ADD_CUSTOMER" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you are using drawable as background??

Comment: it was automatically generated i didn't add that drawable as the background and i'm trying as much to avoid editing so i won't mess it up...any suggestion on editing

Comment: It's because of wrong 9patch images, the .9patch images in your package is corrupted or somehow destroyed, You should again download rar from Actionbar Bar Genrator.

Comment: Wow! i did that and it worked...i had actually done that before and it didn't work.Thanks a lot!!! saved me a lot of stress.